# /etc/fstab: parse error: ignore entry at line

Tags: linux, bash, fstab

I have scrip with function:

```
mount_share () {

    mkdir /data
    echo //$STORAGE_NAME.file.core.windows.net/$STORAGE_SHARE /data cifs vers=3.0,username=$STORAGE_NAME,password=$STORAGE_KEY,dir_mode=0755,file_mode=0644,serverino >> /etc/fstab
    mount -a

}
```

After execution - `mount` returns me an error:

`root@xx255rs2sptry000001:~# mount -a
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error: ignore entry at line 9.`

Same error if I'm trying to `sed` manually:

```
root@xx255rs2sptry000001:~# STORAGE_NAME=ggg
root@xx255rs2sptry000001:~# STORAGE_KEY=sakey
root@xx255rs2sptry000001:~# STORAGE_SHARE=sashare
root@xx255rs2sptry000001:~# echo //$STORAGE_NAME.file.core.windows.net/$STORAGE_SHARE /data cifs vers=3.0,username=$STORAGE_NAME,password=$STORAGE_KEY,dir_mode=0755,file_mode=0644,serverino >> /etc/fstab
root@xx255rs2sptry000001:~# cat /etc/fstab 
# CLOUD_IMG: This file was created/modified by the Cloud Image build process
UUID=e990f8b3-1d6b-4615-8280-8ead4ed2fe7c       /        ext4   defaults,discard        0 0

# CLOUD_IMG: This file was created/modified by the Cloud Image build process
# The following is used to dynamically configured additional
# NICs. Do not remove unless you know what you are doing.
none /etc/network/interfaces.dynamic.d tmpfs   nodev,noexec,nosuid,size=64K 0 0
/dev/disk/cloud/azure_resource-part1    /mnt    auto    defaults,nofail,x-systemd.requires=cloud-init.service,comment=cloudconfig       0       2
//ggg.file.core.windows.net/sashare /data cifs vers=3.0,username=ggg,password=sakey,dir_mode=0755,file_mode=0644,serverino
root@xx255rs2sptry000001:~# mount -a
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error: ignore entry at line 9.
```

I tried to close variables in "" - but no luck:

`echo "//$STORAGE_NAME.file.core.windows.net/$STORAGE_SHARE /data cifs vers=3.0,username=$STORAGE_NAME,password=$STORAGE_KEY,dir_mode=0755,file_mode=0644,serverino" >> /etc/fstab`

`echo //"$STORAGE_NAME".file.core.windows.net/"$STORAGE_SHARE" /data cifs vers=3.0,username="$STORAGE_NAME",password="$STORAGE_KEY",dir_mode=0755,file_mode=0644,serverino >> /etc/fstab`

And so on.

The entry in `/etc/fstab` looks absolutely correct, but...

What I'm doing wrong here?

If add mount entry manually, with `vim` and without variables - everything works fine.

Azure file share documentation - [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-how-to-use-files-linux).

Comment: cat out /etc/fstab with -v to make sure there are no spurious characters in there.

Comment: Also you have no firth and sixth fields i.e. 0 and 0.

Comment: @RamanSailopal Thanks! `cat -v` show me the problem: `//ggg.file.core.windows.net/sashareM-BM- /dataM-BM- cifsM-BM- vers=3.0,username=ggg,password=sakey,dir_mode=0755,file_mode=0644,serverino`
Not shure yet where `M-BM-` came from but this is the reason. Could you add you comment as answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use:

```
cat -v /etc/fstab
```

This will show any spurious character causing any problems.

Comment: Cool. helped with problem copying nfs mount line from fstab help page on a wiki (vi and terminal copy/paste gnome). cat -v showed: '192.168.128.100:/vol/dataM-BM-  M-BM-  M-BM-  M-BM-  M-BM- /dataM-BM-  M-BM-  M-BM-  M-BM-  M-BM-  nfs'. Removing the apparent whitespace and replacing with one space solved it.